# How to data transpose in sql view?

Tags: mysql, plsql-developer

```
Table1
Name   CITY       RANK
Manish New delhi   A
Akash  New delhi   A
Akash  Aligarh     B
Vinay  Barh        C
```

I have to transpose like

```
Name   New Delhi    Aligarh   Barh
Manish    A         NULL      NULL
Akash     A          B        NULL    
Vinay     NULL      NULL       C
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a Stored Procedure](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot) to generate the `SELECT` needed.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged on dba.stackexchange.com. Nice page BTW, and I've visited your site before - again, nice work!

Comment: OK, @Vérace, how should I have answered this without being "link-only"?  (Thanks for the praise.  I did it 25 years ago in Perl, but only recently realized that a SP could do it easily.)

Comment: Post the most relevant content into the answer - but **do** keep the link.

Comment: Hmmm... The relevant content is the whole SP.  But then that needs explaining.  That leads to copying most of the blog here??

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that no rule is absolute.